# Is there a way to write a java code that accepts a number m in the open interval (11,15) and a number n in the closed interval (12,20)

Tags: java

The program is to generate an m*n multiplication table, where n is the number of columns and m is the number of rows

Comment: Use multidimension arrays

Answer (score 0):

The subject is

- how to write a *for* loop
- what is open and what is closed w.r.t. an interval

Probably already known:

- A closed interval `[a, z]` also contains `a` and `z`.
- An open interval `(a, z)` does not contain `a` and `z`.

In Computer Science left-closed, right-open, like `[0, n)` is often used.
That way one can simply glue intervals together `[0, m) + [m, n) == [0, n)`.
Also *for* loops and zero indexed arrays follow this convention: `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`.

```
for (int m = 11+1; m < 15; ++m) { // Open interval 12, 13, 14
    for (int n = 12; n <= 20; ++n) { // Closed interval 12, 13, ..., 19, 20
       System.out.printf("Multiplication table %d x %d:%n", m, n);
       for (int row = 1; row <= m; ++row) {
           for (int column = 1; column <= n; ++column) {
               System.out.printf("%4d ", row*column);
           }
           System.out.println(); // Line break;
       }
    }
}
```